# Nagios core 4.1.1 error: Unable to get process status

Tags: nagios

When start to connect through http://localhost/nagios, i could get "Daemon running with PID 2027 ". but connect through http://own_ip/nagios, i couldn't get "Daemon running status" instead its showing as "Unable to get process status ".

**Daemon running status**
**http://postimg.org/image/6wgzsgr6p/**

**Daemon not running status**
**http://postimg.org/image/59m9qqrvl/**